# how to add same timer in multiple window form in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

how can i add same timer in multiple window form in c#.i am trying to develope an M.C.Q s app so when user answer first question if time is 25 second that time after clicking next how can i show the running time in next form.Thank you

Comment: you can use a global timer for whole project which can be in a static class or you can use MDI winforms .1st one is simpler than 2nd if you're a beginner

Comment: May not contribute to your question but: Lets say you got 25 questions, do you have 25 Forms then?

Comment: let i've added 10 question in my app and total time is 3 minutes.Timer starts from 0 and when user answer the first one and click next then i want to know that how can the timer show the final time of question one as initial time of question two

Comment: I would suggest to manage the program from module Program.cs and then launch forms from that parent module. Then, you can have, as suggested a timer in a Global static class

Comment: Do you mean a timer or do you what the time elapsed to be displayed?

Comment: timer displayed on label

Comment: You don't need to use multiple forms. Just use a single form. Use data-binding and  move between record. Also if for any reason you need to use multiple screens, use UserControl or event non-top-level forms and host them in a single form.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass instance of timer as a parameter to next form constructor, so you can carry forward same time in next form.

Lets take an example:

You have first question on `From1` and on `Submit function` you want to show next form something like this:

```
public class Form1
{
   ...
   public void submit()
   {
       ...
       //Here you are calling form2
       //Pass timer instance a parameter to form2
       Form2 form2Instance = new Form2(timer);
       form2Instance.Show();
   }

}
```

Comment: Prasad can you post an example of that one!

Answer (score 0):

Put your timer as a static member in a form that inherits from Form. All other high level forms should inherit from the one with the timer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share timer across different forms, you have two options.

1: pass timer instance between forms

```
var myTimer = new Timer(...);    
//here this means form1
this.MyTimer = myTimer; 
form2.MyTimer = myTimer;
```

2: make a timer instance static (and public) so you can access it from everywhere

```
public static Timer MyTimer = new Timer(...);
```

Comment: kindly post an example of hat one cuz im begginer

Comment: And the 3rd option that is the most OOP-spirited the one I suggested.:-)